# USB flash drive doesn't remount automatically

Tags: usb

I have a USB flash drive connected to a Dell monitor that's connected to my MacBook Pro with a Thunderbolt 3 cable. If I unplug the MacBook (screen closed), then plug it back in, I'm notified I didn't unmount the disk (it's journaled, and I'm lazy), but wasn't remounted. USB through the monitor still works (my keyboard works), and the device is still recognized:

```
$ sudo ioreg -p IOUSB
+-o Root  <class IORegistryEntry, id 0x100000100, retain 23>
  +-o AppleUSBVHCIBCE Root Hub Simulation@80000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x1000004e2, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 15>
  | +-o ...
  +-o AppleUSBXHCI Root Hub Simulation@14000000  <class AppleUSBRootHubDevice, id 0x100000535, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 10>
  | +-o IOUSBHostDevice@14400000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000231bd, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 15>
  |   +-o IOUSBHostDevice@14450000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000231d8, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 11>
  |   +-o Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.1@14430000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000231f3, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (2 ms), retain 15>
  |   +-o <b>USB3.0 Card Reader@14440000  <class AppleUSBDevice, id 0x1000233be, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (1 ms), retain 11></b>
  +-o ...
```

How can I get the device to be remounted?

Comment: & what happens if you actually eject it properly? [This to preempt the "why do it that way then?" feedback that is bound to follow.]

Comment: It ejects fine, and when I reconnect to the monitor, it's still ejected. I halfway expect that; maybe it's clever enough to know I plugged in a hub, not that I plugged in a USB device. But the mouse reconnects fine.

Comment: Mice don't need to be unmounted. If the symptom is the same when correctly unmounted, I'd be looking at the display's USB implementation. Give the display mfr a shout.

Comment: I found an ancient hint that flash is treated differently than an HDD for something like this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2152391?answerId=10297535022#10297535022

Comment: This suggests unloading the USB storage kernel extension will mount it: https://superuser.com/a/969320/264403