# How to make USB Disk reliably unmount and remount after sleep?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, usb, sleep-wake, mount

I have a Western Digital 5Tb MyPassport USB backup disk, which I attach to my MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.7.

It's a portable machine, which I regularly need to detach from the drive. I've had trouble with corrupted disks, unwanted backups using CPU cycles, and frequent 'You are evil! - next time unmount disk before disconnecting' messages.

So I want to keep the device attached, but only mount it in the middle of the night for a one-off Time Machine backup. No problem, in theory. The script to do that is based on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251491948 . I can even stop the device automounting when I plug it in using https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8567057 (though I'm not using that for now).

But in practice Catalina seems broken. Once an unmount has happened and the machine has had a period of 'sleep' mode, it seems impossible to remount the device using software. Various error messages signal the problem, for example:

```
> diskutil mount MyBackupDisk
Unable to find disk for MyBackupDisk    
> sudo diskutil mount disk3
disk3 is a CoreStorage Logical Volume which failed to mount
```

or, from Disk Utility.app:

```
Could not mount "MyBackupDisk". (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868.)
```

Both diskutil and Disk Utility can still see the device fine. They just won't mount it.

```
> diskutil list
   [...]
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *5.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage MyBackupDisk            5.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS                        +5.0 TB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 78D43612-F176-4610-BA75-A0F2E9CBF44F
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

I've tried every combination I can think of, of diskutil mount, diskutil mountDisk, diskutil eject and the various names and disk IDs. Unplugging the disk and plugging it back in again mounts it; rebooting the Mac does the same. But neither is a solution to the problem.

[USB flash drive doesn't remount automatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381037/usb-flash-drive-doesnt-remount-automatically) suggests reloading the USB mass storage driver. But the kextunload command fails with error "kext in use or retained", which seems reasonable enough. The kextload command succeeds (or fails silently) but makes no difference.

Does anyone know a fix?

- Charles

Comment: It would be very useful to know the exact combinations that you tried but what are the results of the following command to mount the unmounted filesystem- `diskutil mount disk3` ?

Comment: Errr... disk3 is a CoreStorage Logical Volume which failed to mount, as it says above. Sorry if that's not clear.

Comment: Sorry, I should read carefully, obviously I'm not.

Comment: Looks as though there's no easy answer to this one. The Mountain people probably know what to do, but I don't think this is one of the things they support out of the box. For now, I'm simply leaving the disk mounted and ignoring the rude messages from MacOS.